# Windows 10 Explorer: can't distinguish if a file is selected or not on mouse hover

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shell, desktop

On Windows 10 Pro 22H2, I noticed that:

- mouse hover over a Deskotp item, it will be displayed with a light grey rectangular border
- click on the item, the item color / border stays exactly the same, the background color only changes of a few % of brightness

Without moving the mouse cursor away (then in this case, ok, we can see if the item is selected or not, but it requires an extra step), it is thus impossible to distinguish between "selected item" or "not selected".

[image]

Here with a side-by-side comparison screenshot, we *can* maybe tell which one is selected, but on an everyday workflow without a side-by-side example, we cannot easily see the diffrence.

This was never the case with previous versions on Windows. **How to solve this UX problem?**

Example: click on a file, then <kbd>Delete</kbd>, oops, we can't visually check the right file had been selected before deleting, except by adding one more step (moving the mouse away).